# Vim taking really long time to open Ruby files

Tags: ruby, vim

I've noticed that Vim is taking a really long time to open Ruby and ERB (Embedded Ruby) files. I profiled my startup time and these the interesting lines (the full profile is at the bottom if you want   to see it):

```
32980.181  32011.917  32011.917: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/ruby.vim
32980.516  32035.414  022.871: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/eruby.vim
```

As you can see it takes a long time (times are in "msec" apparently) to load ftdetect for Ruby and ERuby. Compare this to ftdetect for HTML and the time it takes to load my .vimrc:

```
952.223  000.626  000.626: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/html.vim
738.536  612.248  534.785: sourcing $HOME/.vimrc
```

Is this normal and is there anything I can do about it? It's pretty infuriating to have to wait ~33 seconds to open a file.

```
times in msec
 clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script
 clock   elapsed:              other lines

000.022  000.022: --- VIM STARTING ---
012.064  012.042: Allocated generic buffers
012.910  000.846: locale set
013.186  000.276: clipboard setup
013.203  000.017: window checked
033.918  020.715: inits 1
034.697  000.779: parsing arguments
034.716  000.019: expanding arguments
077.784  043.068: shell init
079.520  001.736: Termcap init
079.562  000.042: inits 2
080.186  000.624: init highlight
179.889  001.991  001.991: sourcing /Users/davidtuite/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim
564.261  000.178  000.178: sourcing /Users/davidtuite/.vim/filetype.vim
632.475  000.389  000.389: sourcing /Users/davidtuite/.vim/bundle/jst/ftdetect/jst.vim
633.141  055.478  055.089: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
660.587  000.236  000.236: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin.vim
661.081  000.247  000.247: sourcing /Users/davidtuite/.vim/filetype.vim
661.408  000.041  000.041: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
673.005  000.208  000.208: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/indent.vim
699.170  000.901  000.901: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
699.550  007.236  006.335: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/syntax/synload.vim
699.669  008.305  001.069: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim
700.763  000.561  000.561: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
715.774  000.497  000.497: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
716.658  000.452  000.452: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
722.467  010.218  009.269: sourcing /Users/davidtuite/.vim/bundle/solarized/colors/solarized.vim
738.536  612.248  534.785: sourcing $HOME/.vimrc
738.593  046.159: sourcing vimrc file(s)
784.522  000.859  000.859: sourcing /Users/davidtuite/.vim/bundle/ctrlp/autoload/ctrlp/mrufiles.vim
785.378  045.922  045.063: sourcing /Users/davidtuite/.vim/bundle/ctrlp/plugin/ctrlp.vim
816.261  000.454  000.454: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
818.593  000.792  000.792: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/plugin/gzip.vim
820.050  000.921  000.921: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/plugin/matchparen.vim
830.405  002.463  002.463: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
843.038  000.145  000.145: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/plugin/rrhelper.vim
850.425  000.293  000.293: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/plugin/spellfile.vim
851.617  000.671  000.671: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
852.558  000.509  000.509: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tohtml.vim
853.470  000.599  000.599: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
854.255  000.463  000.463: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
854.362  062.537: loading plugins
854.375  000.013: inits 3
875.931  021.556: reading viminfo
875.995  000.064: setting raw mode
876.010  000.015: start termcap
876.062  000.052: clearing screen
952.223  000.626  000.626: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/html.vim
32980.181  32011.917  32011.917: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/ruby.vim
32980.516  32035.414  022.871: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/eruby.vim
33007.912  000.688  000.688: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/indent/ruby.vim
33024.997  001.804  001.804: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/indent/html.vim
33025.207  025.843  023.351: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/indent/eruby.vim
33067.541  000.929  000.929: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/syntax/javascript.vim
33085.205  004.486  004.486: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/syntax/vb.vim
33088.445  002.575  002.575: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/syntax/css.vim
33089.314  039.262  031.272: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/syntax/html.vim
33106.920  003.463  003.463: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/syntax/ruby.vim
33107.112  064.122  021.397: sourcing /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/share/vim/vim73/syntax/eruby.vim
33107.888  107.447: opening buffers
33108.114  000.226: BufEnter autocommands
33108.117  000.003: editing files in windows
33108.319  000.202: VimEnter autocommands
33108.320  000.001: before starting main loop
33127.031  018.711: first screen update
33127.033  000.002: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

Comment: Did you at least open those files to see what they do?

Comment: It's just syntax and cursor movement rules for Ruby files as far as I can tell (my VimScript is pretty weak). They're part of the standard Vim install so I figured I wouldn't have to post the contents of them.

Comment: Those files do a bit of poking around to make sense of their Ruby environment. It's possible that these steps are what takes too long. Also, try to install a more recent build: yours is 7.3.266 while the last patch is 700+.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The delay is attributable to ftplugin/ruby.vim querying the Ruby load path. Just days ago, I significantly improved the speed of this by dropping the querying of Ruby Gems. My Mac currently reports that it takes about 125 ms, a significant improvement. So you might try updating to the latest.

If that still isn't enough, you can disable the load path querying entirely by setting g:ruby_path in your vimrc.

try to add this to .vimrc file (in your home folder):

```
if !empty($MY_RUBY_HOME)
 let g:ruby_path = join(split(glob($MY_RUBY_HOME.'/lib/ruby/*.*')."\n".glob($MY_RUBY_HOME.'/lib/rubysite_ruby/*'),"\n"),',')
endif
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Could you provide a little more information about how you dropped the querying of Ruby Gems please?

Comment: I added those lines to my .vimrc. Looks like a huge speed improvement so far but it's a little early to tell since the problem was only happening on certain cold startups. I will experiment a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set your vim ruby path to something explicit, add this anywhere in your `.vimrc`:

`let g:ruby_path = "/Users/<username>/rbenv/shims/ruby"`

If you're using rbenv, you can just replace `<username>` with your actual Mac user name.

If your ruby path is something else, replace everything within the quotes with the full path to your ruby executable.